# How to send iOS push notifications from my server using Firebase?

Tags: java, ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications, javapns

I'm writing a Java backend where I need to send push notifications to iOS devices.
Note that I want to know how to configure my backend to send push payload to **Firebase** and it should then send it to iOS devices.  I don't want to use direct Apple http/2 sockets because of some constraints. Could you point me to correct documentation of Firebase?

Comment: Have. you tried the searching for Apple developer documentation?

Comment: @Gavin, Why would Apple docs discuss about how to do it using Firebase?

Comment: I think that comment is because you've included the apple-push-notifications as a tag to your question.  Did you review the Getting Started Guide for [Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging)?

Comment: @Jay, Yes, i've updated my answer below too.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer -
We have to use REST APIs exposed by Firebase as follows -

Endpoint: `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`

Body:

```
{  
  "notification" : {
     "title" : "You received simple notification!",
     "badge" : 1,   
     "sound" : "notification.wav",
     "body" : "This push was sent by FCM API",
     "custom" : {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},
     "priority":"high"
  },
  "content_available": false,
  "to":"FIREBASE_DEVICE_TOKEN"
}
```

Don't forget to add headers as follows -

```
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=FIREBASE_SERVER_KEY
```

Don't forget to integrate iOS/Android SDK in your app in order to get the token and to get the push notification delivered!